# Prevent page redirect to SO after PO is saved

Tags: netsuite

In Netsuite, I want to prevent the automatic redirect of the page to the Sales Order when a Dropship or Special Purchase Order is saved.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script on AfterSubmit for the Create event of the PO and look at the 'createdfrom' field.  If the 'createdfrom' field is populated then redirect back to the PO.

```
var dropShipRedirect = {
    afterSubmit : function()
    {
        var record = nlapiGetNewRecord();
        var createdFrom = record.getFieldValue('createdfrom');
        if (createdFrom != null)
        {
            nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', 'purchaseorder', record.getId());
        }
    }
}
```